# Center div inside a parent div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to center a div inside a parent div. The only way I can do it is by using `margin-left` property. The formula is:

```
margin-left = (parent.width/2) - (child.width/2)
```

but I can't get it done via JavaScript because of two things:

1. The width isn't defined in the style thus cannot be accessed via `document.getElementById("child").style.width`
2. `document.getElementById("child").offsetWidth` doesn't give the proper and the correct width for unknown reasons

I am using this code, but as said above, it doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("fb_share").style.marginLeft = parseInt((document.getElementById("vss_border").offsetWidth / 2) - (document.getElementById("fb_share").offsetWidth / 2)) + "px";
</script>
```

If there is any other solution via CSS (but it must be margin-left and no width change) please tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your problem. The child width is set to 691px, so once it tries to center the fb_share div it only sets it by a few pixels.

All you have to do is set the style, e.g:

```
<div id="fb_share" style="width:150px;">
```

Breakdown

Nothing wrong with your javascript.

The child is almost the same width as the parent, causing a minimum center.

Set the child width correct and all should be working fine

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8FE8Y2x8 in this page it doesn't work, i can't understand why O_O

Answer (score 1):

Since you said JavaScript, I can't avoid mentioning jQuery's [position function](http://api.jquery.com/position/):

```
$("#myDiv").position({
   my: "center",
   at: "center",
   of: $('#parent')
});
```

Comment: what is my/at/of, they are not there in the link you shared? it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a quite common question.  The problem is exacerbated by the fact that different browsers understand the stuff differently.  The easiest thing is actually non-CSS:

```
<div id="parent" style="width:100%">
    <div align="center">
       your own stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

However if you need to do this in pure CSS, then the answer will be something like this:

In your CSS:

```
div.parent {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

div.child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Then, in your HTML, you'd have something like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="child">
      Your stuff here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used this (second) approach to centre the entire page content within the browser window (in my case, instead of the first div, I had `<body>`.  If you want to see where I used this, have a look at http://www.ooklnet.com/

Comment: these solutions won't work, especially if there is a floating element on the right with padding property